# Display Message to User instead of empty JSON on HTML when records are empty in the database

Tags: html, json, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

I have an application where I have an html page which takes user input through a textbox.This is a REST Spring Framework and is divided as Controller, Entity, Service, Repository, View and the main application class.

I take an input value and search in the Mongodb database, If the value is present, I return the entity object from Service to Controller. The controller returns the same Entity View object.- PersonView in this case. I get a JSON Data.

The above scenario works well as long as there are records in the database. In case if the record is not present, it returns an empty JSON. My Controller returns Person View Object and I do not wish to change the signature and make the return type as String since in that case it returns the address on my HTML page. 
Considering this, how should I handle the case when there are no records in the database and I wish to display a message on this same HTML page saying there are no records available.

I tried throwing an exception but in this case too, how Do I display message on my HTML considering that my Controller returns JSON object and I do not wish to change its signature?

Controller Class is as below:

```
 public PersonView searchPerson(@PathVariable String pname) {
      List<Person> pList= PersonService.searchPerson(pname);
       PersonView personView = new PersonView();

    personView.setPersonView(pList);



    return personView;
```

EDIT:

Here is the function from personView Class that I call in Controller:

```
  public List<Person> setPersonView() {
    this.personView = personView;
}
```

Here is the service Impl class:

```
    public List<Person> searchPerson(String name) throws Exception {

         List<Person> personlist= new ArrayList<Person>();
       personlist = personRepository.findByName(name);
     if (personlist.isEmpty()) 
            throw new Exception("Records not found in the the database");


        return personlist;

    }
```

Comment: The best way to do this would probably be to just write some JS where you set a variable with the contents of personView (the JSON object). Then run a check, which if the variable is empty, updates the relevant HTML element with your message.

Comment: @dukedevil294 Thank you! That was initial thought but then is there a way to do using the Java code? Curious to know how that would be done?

Comment: @dukedevil294 Also how can I do it if it is possibe to do by throwing exception in the Repository class?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here. There will be some logic in the PersonView class that iterates through the pList and that's likely where you would put your decision point on how to reflect zero records. You should include that code with your question. Also the question isn't specific enough. There are thousands of ways you could represent an empty database to your user. You could test for pList.count == 0 and insert one line saying "No Records", you could have a <div> that is invisible when there are records but shows when there are none.

Comment: You could use something from Spring like the Model object (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html). So your check could be done in the controller and then you set your message with addAttribute to your model. But you'll still need something on the front end that checks if that model attribute needs to be displayed or not.

Comment: @Mikey Check the updated question

Comment: @dukedevil294 I have updated my question. Please have a look and see if you can help in making changes to this.

Comment: Can you add controller code?

Comment: I think what you need is a way to handle that exception. Have a look at: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html

Comment: @Saurabh I have added the Function from the controller class.

Comment: @Saurabh Thanks for prompt replies. I did try throwing exceptions in my code as shown above, but could you help in modifying it so that I display error message on my html page without changing the signatures of the methods and classes that I showed above.

Comment: If you don't want to change the signature, then create a custom exception extending runtime exception and throw that. You can use ResponseEntityExceptionHandler to check if the exception of that type is thrown and send the response message in the Response entity.

Comment: @Saurabh Appreciate you with the above explanation but could you show me how it is done? I am bit overwhelmed and same time new with this. I mean could you modify my code ?

Comment: @Saurabh My condition is that I do not wish to change signature of any methods but somehow throw exception and pass a message on my html saying "yhere are no records"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom Exception class:

```
public class EntityNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public EntityNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Now, in you controller code:

```
public List<Person> searchPerson(String name) {

     List<Person> personlist= new ArrayList<Person>();
     personlist = personRepository.findByName(name);
     if (personlist.isEmpty()) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Records not found in the the database");
     }
     return personlist;
}
```

After that you can try something like this in you controller class:

```
private static final MappingJacksonJsonView JSON_VIEW = new MappingJacksonJsonView();

@ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
public ModelAndView handleNotFoundException( Exception ex )
{
    return new ModelAndView(JSON_VIEW, "error", new ErrorMessage("No Record in Db") );
}
```

Your ErrorMessage class can be a simple POJO:

```
public class ErrorMessage {
    private String message;
    ErrorMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you have to create that class.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I get this output!! 
{"error":{"message":"No Record in Db"}}
Really appreciate your help with this. Although I am good with this, can you guide me as to how I can  just display "No Records in database. "

Comment: Instead of `new ErrorMessage("No Record in Db")`, just do: `"No Record in Db"`. Also, if you do so you will not need ErrorMessage class.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help with this. I will mark your answer as correct. Was wondering if you could suggest me a good tutorial to understand spring framework and REST

Answer (score 0):

Although already answered, I will add some points here.

Please note that at some point of time you will have a requirement to send the 
headers, Response body (with different Objects). So consider using ResponseEntity Object which will be a wrapper to your List. Here is the sample code.

```
public  ResponseEntity<List<Person>> searchPerson(String name) {

 List<Person> personlist= new ArrayList<Person>();
 personlist = personRepository.findByName(name);
 if (personlist.isEmpty()) {
  return new ResponseEntity(new EntityNotFoundException("Records not found in the the database"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
 }
 return new ResponseEntity(personlist , HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Response Entity Object provides flexibility to greater extent. Read the documentation here.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadocapi/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html